# Tcl: String replacement in exec, but not as a single argument

Tags: tcl

In a Tcl script, I want to execute a command like:

```bash
set result [exec ${exe} ${options} ${prog}]
```

Where `options` is something like `set options "-a -b -c"` or `set options ""`.  But that does not work because what's executed is like

`${exe} "-a -b -c" ${prog}` or `${exe} "" ${prog}`

and not like

`${exe} -a -b -c ${prog}` or `${exe}  ${prog}`

How can I expand the string so that it is not a single argument?  The documentation says that `[]` replaces the result of a command, but

```bash
set result [exec ${exe} [puts ${options}] ${prog}]
```

does not do what the documentation is promissing...

Comment: try argument expansion `{*}` like this : `set result [exec ${exe} {*}${options} ${prog}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options, depending on exactly what you want.

The classic Tcl technique is to use argument expansion syntax:

```
set result [exec $exe {*}$options $prog]
```

But if you want use shell syntax instead, you instead do some variant on this:

```
set result [exec sh -c "exec '$exe' $options '$prog'"]
```

(Assuming that `$exe` and `$prog` don't contain single quotes.)

Comment: Ancient versions of Tcl (8.4 and before) use `eval` instead of expansion, but that was much harder to use safely (to the point of being a common source of bugs). It isn't recommended at all now.

Comment: Using unquoted words in the shell can have unexpected results: with `set options {-a -b -c *}` the shell will expand `*` to the list of files in the current directory. Stick to the Tcl technique.